# How do I permanently keep a copy of someone else's public files on Google Drive on my own Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

There are probably about 20 GBs of videos that I want to keep on my own Google Drive that I found publicly available on someone's Google Drive. I tried adding the files via the option *Add to my Drive* but that only added a shortcut on my drive. When I check the size of my drive, It says that it's about 278 MBs including 44 MBs of GMail. How can I keep a full-fledged copy of all the files without painstakingly downloading them and then uploading them manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the list of files on Google Drive, over the file name do Right click > Make a copy.

The files will be named as "Copy of *original file name*". An option to avoid this is to use a script or a third-party tool.

NOTES:

1. The script complexity will depend on several factors, like the number of files to be copied, if you want also copy the folder structure, etc.
2. Nowadays Google Drive allows file owners to block viewers from copying files

Related

- [How to batch copy folders+files from others' share to my Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58386/88163)
- [How to copy a shared folder into my own Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120362/88163)

Comment: Thanks it worked! But all files now say **copy of <filename>**. I guess I could live with that.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the file to your Drive, you can change the name of the file. Right click (or two-finger tap on a trackpad) the name of the file and select "Rename" and then you can change it to your preferred name.

Comment: No, what I meant was that each file now said _copy of <filename>_. I wanted it so that each copy said _<filename>_ only.

Comment: As far I know, you will have to change the name of each file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, put these files in a folder, and you can then make a copy of the folder. To make a copy of a folder, you can use tools from reliable 3rd party. Doing it this way, your file will not be renamed as "Copy of xxxx".  Here is the reference.

GSuiteTips is a website that provides useful tricks and tips around google workspace. It has one of the useful features called the Copy Folder feature which allows copying files from one folder of google drive to another. So, using this we can copy files/folders from Shared with Me to My Drive.

https://gsuitetips.com/tools/copy-folder/